# Django/Wagtail: Inherit the fields defined in another form page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

We are currently working on a Wagtail project which needs us to have two different forms (`AbstractEmailForm`) with the same user-defined form fields (`AbstractFormField`).

More precisely, the user defines a form page which fields musst be filled out with short keywords in the frontend. Afterwards, another form page is accepting longer texts which are based on these keywords. Therefore, this second page is using fields named the same as the first keyword form page fields.

We already tried to solve this problem for a few hours now and we came to the conclusion that this has likely to be done by getting the form fields out of the instance of the first form page, but I could not yet figure out how this is done. Propably by defining a `OneToOneField`, but I have no idea on how to get data out of this, I feel like I tried everything.

Comment: Wagtail's `forms` module is designed to allow content authors (i.e. non-developers using the Wagtail admin backend) to define forms for end-users to fill in. From your description, it sounds like no form fields are actually being defined editorially here - it's a form being built by a developer, with application-specific logic, for end-users to fill in. If that's the case, then `wagtail.contrib.forms` is the wrong tool for the job - you should use the Django forms framework instead.